# Google Console Internal App Sharing no longer works

Tags: android, google-developers-console, internal-app-sharing

I was regularly uploading apk files to google console's internal app sharing page. However today when I open the the same link i.e. https://play.google.com/console/u/0/internal-app-sharing it has gone blank. I have tried opening it from different browsers etc, nothing works. Is this a new bug or perhaps a downtime?
[image]

Comment: https://downdetector.co.uk/status/google-play/

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Browser dev console shows the app sharing tries to load some data, but can not find it. So someone just broke the code or google server are down. Hopefully not for long, but its already over 20 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, seems there was a temporary blip at their end.